# Interupt widget1_handler using widget2 (ipywidgets)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

The following piece of code is meant to be representative of the problem I'm working on:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

a = widgets.ToggleButton(
    value=False,
    description='start',
    disabled=False,
    icon=''
)

b = widgets.ToggleButton(
    value=False,
    description='stop',
    disabled=True,
    icon=''
)

def func1(change):
    if change['new'] is True:
        a.disabled = True
        b.disabled = False
        for i in range(1000000):
            if b.value is False:
                print(i)
            elif b.value is True:
                break

a.observe(func1, 'value')

display(widgets.VBox([a, b]))
```

What I want to do is break out of the for loop that's initiated upon clicking `a`, by clicking `b`. The above code does not work, and I can't seem to find a similar problem/solution elsewhere. It seems like `b.value` does not get updated for the for loop even upon clicking `b`.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there another way around this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html#Updating-a-widget-in-the-background). You will need to use a thread in order to let other widgets change whilst one loop is running.

```python
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import time

a = widgets.ToggleButton(
    value=False,
    description='start',
    disabled=False,
    icon=''
)

b = widgets.ToggleButton(
    value=False,
    description='stop',
    disabled=True,
    icon=''
)

def work():
    a.disabled = True
    b.disabled = False
    for i in range(1000000):
        time.sleep(1)
        if b.value is False:
            print(i)
        elif b.value is True:
            break

def func1(change):
    if change['new'] is True:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=work)
        thread.start()

a.observe(func1, 'value')

display(widgets.VBox([a, b]))
```